# jQuery PHP Collapse repetitive line breaks into a single one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I know that there are similar questions to this but I couldn't help noticing that this question has never been asked or may be it is impossible but I need to set a maximum line break for text entered in a textarea or any other html element.

example one

```
<ul class="generic-list">
<li class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit.




    Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
</li>
```

On a web page that preserves the blank lines no matter the gap between the text lines.

I know there are some css3 functions but they can only control whitespaces  and not sure they can limit blank line length.

I would like the code above to look like this.

example two.

```
    <li class="item">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
    Lor
```

the `<li>` tags are just for reference. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How much is "maximum"? 10? maybe you want just `white-space: pre` (a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space))?

Comment: no, am talking about empty lines not pre tags

Comment: Okey, let me fix the title...

Comment: If such an html is being generated by server, then I would recommend to process it on server side. Does it came from DB? if yes, maybe it would be a good option to process it before setting to DB... only once.

Comment: yes, that is the reason why i wonna reduce the multiple empty lines before DB processes take place

Comment: So, if it's initially some user input, then the UX should be taken into the account: maybe it would be better to show him (the user) that the extra lines are being collapsed right during the input?

Comment: True, but then again I allow upto I blank line which is pretty standard

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156867/discussion-between-dennisrec-and-dhilt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to regex on your PHP while load the content before echo it

```
$thecontent = "YOUR_CONTENT_HERE";
preg_replace('/(?:(?:\r\n|\r|\n)\s*){2}/s', "\n\n", $thecontent);
```

Comment: Thanks for this hack.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can `split()` the string at line breaks into an array then `filter()` out empty lines and `join()` array using line break as delimiter

```js
let str = `
Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit.




Lorem ipsum dolor sit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit.`;

let res = str.split('\n').filter(line => line.trim()).join('\n');

document.getElementById('result').value = res;
```

```css
textarea{ width:100%; height:200px}
```

```html
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```